# Get actual reach for several ads using Facebook Ads API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm looking for a way to get the overall reach for several ads on facebook (using facebook ads api). This reach should not be the sum of all ads reach, because if the same user saw 2 different ads, it should count him as 1 and not as 2.

It should not be a regular sum, but the number of unique users who were exposed to all or some of these ads.

Comment: How would you be able to determine that without the unique set of user IDs who saw each ad? I don't think that data is available anywhere in Facebook's system, even in the first party ads tools

Comment: I'm not sure if this data is available but I know that if you generating facebook report for the whole adaccount than the reach you'll get there is the unique reach.. I want the same thing for selected ads and not all of them

Comment: Where in Facebook's reports is that statistic? Are you able to run the same report at the account level with the reportstats endpoint? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid access token for the user that created those ads, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
HTTP GET https://graph.facebook.com/act_ACCOUNTID/reportstats?date_preset=yesterday&data_columns=['adgroup_id','reach']
```

Then in the response of the call, you should see something like

```
{ data: [ { adgroup_id: 1, reach: 100 } ] }
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/ for the skinny on the ad report stats API.

Comment: Thank you Jay, But than I'll get the reach for every one of the ads in this account. The sum of this reach is not equals to the combined unique reach.